# How to find string length in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

First of all I am brand new to ruby, so forgive me for being a noob.
There is a section on my site where users can add comments. Looking through the `controller` folder, I found a `comments_controller.rb` file. In that file there is a variable `@comment`.
I want to display the length of whatever comment the user adds on my `show.html.erb` file. (this is the page where comments are displayed). From my very limited understanding of Rails, I have tried to put `<%= @comment.length %>` into my `show.html.erb` file, but I get a NoMethod error. I have no idea what to do, someone please help!

[image]

Am I looking at the right section?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `@comment` returns an instance of `Comment` model, which is **not** a string and doesn't have `length` method defined on it. You are looking to measure an `attribute` of that model. So, first find out which attribute you are interested in and then call `length` on that attribute.

E.g. `@comment.body.length`.

Comment: am I looking at the right section ? (see edited question)